# Looking for functioning dice servers

Tags: dice, tool-recommendation, remote

The first page of Google results returns dice servers that are no longer functional. Do you guys have any working ones bookmarked?

The server must be capable of sending the results to two or more email addresses and rolling D&D ability scores (4d6, drop lowest).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an easy one to use. It should cover everything you need.

http://www.pbegames.com/roller/

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps this would be helpful:

[EvilDM Dice Server: Roll Dice](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/extras/dice-roller)

You can enter (where the bold corresponds to the empty fields):
Roll **4** d **6** +**0** and keep the top **3**, **6** times for **ability scores**

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer something local, I wrote [NetDice](http://goo.gl/mNCFk). While it doesn't send emails, you can use it locally or as a server/client for real-time communication. I could add an email feature if a few people would be interested.

The roll you want would be rolled as 4d6ch3 (ch=choose highest).

Comment: If you implemented email, I would host it on a publicly available server.

Comment: Sounds good! I will look into adding it as part of 0.7. I've not played via email before, so any important features/use case suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: I've released 0.7.0, with email support! Please take a look, let me know what you think.
NetDice - http://goo.gl/mNCFk

Comment: I tried setting it up and noticed that it's not at all designed to run without a GUI. Remember that email servers don't have that. Your app should run as a service and plug into Postfix to receive rolls and send results.

Comment: NetDice is entirely GUI-based. I set up email mode to be able to email out from gmail accounts as a proof-of-concept. I can add other domains by request. I don't want to have to deal with running or interfacing with an email server, since most users would rather have something that 'just works'. I am looking into making a cli-mode, but it'll be a while for that functionality.