# Are there any good online dicerollers similar to the now mostly defunct Invisible Castle?

Tags: tools, dice, tool-recommendation, play-by-post

I used to use Invisible Castle's roller which was based off of OpenRPG.  Worked great, but it looks like the site has been pretty much gutted and is mostly defunct.  The roller still works but I'm not sure how well the site would hold up to actually building a good proper campaign anymore.  Is there anything that's still in good condition that has a similar sort of function?  Dice roller, records each roll made, can link to the rolls, etc?

The [Cheat Proof online die roller](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48452/cheat-proof-online-die-roller) asked more about using pregenerated ID's and most of the answers directly relate to that strategy.  And Invisible Castle is specifically listed as well but as I stated the site is mostly defunct.  The roller still functions, but the rest of the site is empty.  Others listed were using emails, which I may not be able to use for what I intended.  Invisible Castle was pretty much unique in its features and I haven't found anything like it in years.  The closest thing listed in that question to what I needed is RPOL.net but its dicerollers are only accessible to people with an account and listed as part of the campaign.  For what I was looking for there was a possibility of many people coming and going and as long as they have the campaign name I can check the logs well and Invisible Castle worked great for that but is no longer being maintained it seems.

Invisible Castle's features, as I know them, include the following.

- Trackable dice rolls first and foremost
- Ability for anyone to jump in and make a roll for the campaign as long as they have an account
- Trackable by character name
- Rather decent rolling mechanics (allowed for drop lowest/highest, exploding, etc)
- No account needed if you're cool with not tagging the Campaign
- Comments could be added into the rolls

Answer (score 3):

A guy I know has [this site](http://lapo.it/rpg/dadi.php). It might not be as good and versatile as the invisible castle, but it's [open source](http://lapo.it/rpg/dadi.phps) and you can run your own version, where only your campaign's rolls are stored (and it will never go down as long as you keep it operative yourself).

Comment: Your second link intermittently leads to a **500 - Internal Server Error** page. It seems to alternate between working and not working.

Comment: @Dyndrilliac maybe it rolls a d2 to determine whether to work or not!

Answer (score 3):

## [Myth-Weavers](http://www.myth-weavers.com/) is an RPG Play-by-Post site which meets all but one of your listed criteria.

With wide support for a variety of game systems and dice mechanics, this seems like your best option. In addition to a robust built-in dice roller, it also provides everything else you would need for a PbP game: message board, character sheets, and even has some nifty random generation tools. This is what I used prior to migrating my own long-distance campaigns to Roll20. Interestingly, Myth-Weavers wasn't mentioned in [Cheat-proof online die roller?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/48452/cheat-proof-online-die-roller)

The only criteria on your list that they don't meet is that every user must register for an account. There are no features for anonymous usage. However, registering is free and takes very little effort. Due to the ubiquity of advertising spam bots, this is pretty par for the course and I don't think it's too much to ask your players to provide a verifiable email address in order to participate.

The provided dice roller includes built-in anti-cheating functionality. From their [wiki](http://www.myth-weavers.com/wiki/index.php/Help:Myth-Weavers:DiceRoller):

> In order to prevent cheating, the dice here are programmed to show a big, highlighted warning if anyone tampers with the results or presentation of the rolls. These are the conditions that will cause a warning to appear.
>
> 1. Altering the order of dice in a post.
> 2. Editing the dice in a dice string.
> 3. Adding new dice strings before or between existing dice
> 4. Deleting already-rolled dice from a post.
>
> If you accidentally cause a warning to occur, it can be fixed by returning the dice to their original order and contents, if possible. Conditions 2 and 3 above cannot be fixed completely. Many other dice rolling systems allow reposting deleted rolls in order to get a better result. This isn’t possible here. Dice roll results are always saved and deletion and then subsequent reposting of dice roll will simply lead to the same results.
>
> Note that you can still go back and edit the text of a post without causing a warning, as long as you don't cause any changes in the dice.

Comment: Just want to provide a warning, that I've made mistakes and ended up getting dice rerolled with the warning when I did not intend to. I suggest playing around to see how it works. (sometimes editing text before the die roll can have this affect.)

Answer (score 1):

[Hamate](http://dicelog.com/dice) meets most of your requirements, if in a roundabout way.  A dice log can be opened per-player or I believe for a campaign, with registered users being able to roll in the log and keep records.  Unregistered users cannot access the dice logs but can make individual rolls with verification numbers a GM can use to make sure the rolls are legitimate.  There's also the option to send results by email, preventing someone from rolling until they get something they like and then just passing those results on.